# Redis multi client server architecture

Tags: redis, hiredis

I am having a application which is using redis. Its a two box system means the application is in HA(High availability architecture). When a box go down i want to recover the all the data on that box to sync  with first box and vice versa. Is is possible with redis ???

Answer (score 1):

You can configure redis to persist all data to disk and configure your machines in master slave replication.

Redis sentinel (built in redis 2.7+) can be also used to do automatic failure recovery (promote one slave as master when master is down)

You can find all the documentation you need about this on the redis docs website http://redis.io/documentation

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but both of my servers will be handling data so how much time it will take to sync ??? 

does write to redis master server auto sync to redis slaves ??? How much time it take to sync a data written in master ???
is this time is configurable ??

Comment: slaves are kept in sync master as much as possible (depending on traffic / IO capabilities there might be some replication lag), when a slave connects to a master it syncs and then replays all the commands that are sent to the master.